# 2 different Apps with same Entities for Sync with Simperium

Tags: ios, core-data, simperium

I have 2 different apps created on https://simperium.com.
These apps have same entity names for core data. Now it syncs only the Entities which are not in app 1.

I have to rename the Entities in app 2? Is this a bug?

Answer (score 0):

By default, data doesn't sync across two different apps in Simperium. Each app has its own, secured namespace. It's likely whatever you're trying to do can be accomplished in another way. If you're able to provide more details, I'm happy to take a look.